# BURG can't detect filesystem in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: dual-boot, 16.10, burg

It's years now that I'm using BURG, I know it's no longer in development but was working fine for me and I knew how to tweak this or that to accomplish what I wanted.
I had Ubuntu 16.04 and like the previous version sometime I had to use **burg-install** and everything was fine.
Now I installed Yakkety Yak in place and when I try to run burg-install this happens.

```
/usr/sbin/burg-probe: error: unknown filesystem.
Auto-detection of a filesystem module failed.
Please specify the module with the option `--modules' explicitly.
```

I tried to install in MBR or Ubuntu partition but the result is the same.
I don't understand why it stoped working on 16.10 as my partitions are the same as before.
I don't know how to use the --modules option either.

Comment: I tried with --modules=ext and I can install it but then if I try to use update-burg to create a .cfg file burg-probe stops everything with "unknown filesystem" again.
So I tried to copy a backup burg.cfg I did before the fresh intall and burg starts when using burg-emu via shell (I won't try to boot normally until everithing is fine) but there are some errors.

    error: can't open `/boot/burg/themes/custom/theme_ubuntu'.
    error: unknown command `vmenu'.
    error: no such device: --Ubuntu partition UUID--.

Answer (score 1):

I'm told that BURG doesn't work with UEFI/GPT systems. It's way outdated.

Comment: Alright but worked fine on 16.04

Comment: So, no other way to fix this and install on GPT/EFI?

Comment: You might look at rEFInd. Info at http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/